# Wrong value being passed to controller from form_tag and modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index view that includes this code...

```
 <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
   ...
   <div class="modal micromodal-slide" id="modal-1" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal__overlay" tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>
            <div class="modal__container" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-1-title">
              <header class="modal__header">
                <h3 class="modal__title" id="modal-1-title">
                  Share Job
                </h3>
                <button class="modal__close" aria-label="Close modal" data-micromodal-close></button>
              </header>
              <main class="modal__content" id="modal-1-content">
                <p>
                Enter an email address below to share this job to a friend.
                <%= form_tag({controller: "jobs",
                              action: "email_job",
                              job_id: job.id},
                              method: "post") do %>
                <p><%= text_field_tag(:email_address, nil, placeholder: 'Email Address', :job_id => job.id)%></p>
                <p><%= text_area(:message, :text, placeholder: 'Optional Message',  size: "30x10") %></p>
                <p><button class="btn">Send</button></p>
              <% end %>
                </p>
              </main>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     ...
```

So for each job I have a share link and when the user clicks on that link to "share" a job they get a modal pop up that displays the form. My issue is that `job.id` returns the same job id (the first job in the database) for each job.

Comment: I added the modal code above. I think I need a unique id for the one or more of the divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can really just set this up as a normal nested resource and use a virtual model:

```
resources :jobs do
  resources :shares
end
```

```
# app/models/share.rb
# This model does not inherit from ActiveRecord::Base and does not have a table
class Share 
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :email_adress
  attribute :message
  validates_presence_of :email
end
```

```
# shares/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: [job, local_assigns[:share] || Share.new]) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.text_field(:email_address, placeholder: 'Email Address') %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_area_field(:message, placeholder: "Optional Message",  size: "30x10") %></p>
  <%= f.submit('Send') %>
<% end %>

# shares/new.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'form', job: @job, share: @share %>
```

The `shares/new.html.erb` view is just used in case the validations fail. This is easier then trying to re-render the entire view that the user cam from and less hacky than redirecting back.

You can add the form to your jobs index by:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= render partial: 'shares/form', job: job %>
<% end %>
```

The controller is just your average nested CRUD controller except you just call `valid?` instead of saving.

```
class SharesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_job
  # POST /jobs/:job_id/shares
  def create
    if @share.valid?
      # @todo send email
      redirect_to @job, success: 'Job shared'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
  private
  def set_job
    @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  end

  def job_params
    params.require(:share).permit(:email_address, :message)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this max...its an interesting way to do it. Sorry for the hassle, but my issue was with the modal I was using. See my solution I posted.

Answer (score 0):

This was a modal issue where the modal code needs a unique id. See my solution below. note I added `id="modal-<%=job.id%>"` for the id's.

```
  <div class="modal micromodal-slide" id="modal-<%=job.id%>" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal__overlay" tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>
                <div class="modal__container" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-<%=job.id%>-title">
                  <header class="modal__header">
                    <h3 class="modal__title" id="modal-<%=job.id%>-title">
                      Share Job
                    </h3>
                    <button class="modal__close" aria-label="Close modal" data-micromodal-close></button>
                  </header>
                  <main class="modal__content" id="modal-<%=job.id%>-content">
                    <p>
                    Enter an email address below to share this job to a friend.
                    <%= form_tag({controller: "jobs",
                                  action: "email_job",
                                  job_id: job.id},
                                  method: "post") do %>
                    <p><%= text_field_tag(:email_address, nil, placeholder: 'Email Address', :job_id => job.id)%></p>
                    <p><%= text_area(:message, :text, placeholder: 'Optional Message',  size: "30x10") %></p>
                    <p><button class="btn">Send</button></p>
                  <% end %>
                    </p>
                  </main>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```